# HTML table creation in lightning component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript

I'm trying to create a dynamic HTML table in lightning component, but have issues on capturing the clicked record from the table. Can someone please suggest what approach should I take. In the below code Event is returning to null and would like to fetch the record which I clicked on for further processing.

Ex: when I click on United Oil & Gas, UK need to get the AccountId of respective Account.

```
({
    createTable : function(component, event, helper) {
        var JSONResult;
        var action = component.get("c.getAccount");
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){

            JSONResult = response.getReturnValue();
            var col = [];
            var colwithHeaderName = [];

            var table = document.createElement("table");
            table.setAttribute("class", "slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_cell-buffer slds-scrollable_x");
            var tr = table.insertRow(-1); 
            console.log('**col**'+col);
            for (var i = 1; i < col.length; i++) {
                var th = document.createElement("th");      
                th.setAttribute("class","slds-text-title_caps");
                var colHeaderName=col[i];

                if(colHeaderName.indexOf("__c")>-1) colHeaderName=colHeaderName.substring(0,colHeaderName.indexOf("__c"));
                if(colHeaderName.indexOf("_")>-1) colHeaderName=colHeaderName.replace("_"," ");
                th.innerHTML = colHeaderName;
                colwithHeaderName.push(colHeaderName);
                tr.appendChild(th);
            }


            for (var i = 0; i < JSONResult.length; i++) {
                tr = table.insertRow(-1);
                for (var j = 1; j < col.length; j++) {
                    var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);

                    if(j==1){
                        var aLink = document.createElement("a");

                        aLink.setAttribute("value",JSONResult[i][col[j]]);
                        aLink.setAttribute("data-record",j);

                         aLink.setAttribute("data-recId",JSONResult[i][col[0]]);

                        aLink.innerHTML=JSONResult[i][col[j]];
                        var recordId=JSONResult[i][col[0]];                       
                        var index=i;
                        aLink.setAttribute("id",recordId);
                        aLink.addEventListener("click", function(component,event){
                            // Would like fetch the record Id of the selected record from dataTable                           
                    });
                    tabCell.appendChild(aLink);
                }
                else{
                    tabCell.innerHTML = JSONResult[i][col[j]];
                }
            }
        }


        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);


    },
    readTable : function(component, event, helper) {
        //Read table rows
        var staticTableDOM=document.getElementById('divTest').getElementsByTagName('table')[0]; 
        console.log('*** Table ***');
        console.log(staticTableDOM);
        console.log('*** Table Rows ***');
        console.log(staticTableDOM.rows);
        console.log('*** Table 1st Row cells ***');
        console.log(staticTableDOM.rows[0].cells);
    } 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

In a function like you're setting, there's only one parameter, the event:

```
aLink.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
```

To get back in the Aura life cycle, in order to set attributes or call other controller methods, you need $A.getCallback:

```
aLink.addEventListener('click', $A.getCallback(function(event) {
  // Event handler code here
}));
```

However, doing this is problematic. It would be better to render your table using the template:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!accounts}" var="account">
  <tr>
   <aura:iteration items="{!account.fields}" var="field">
     <td>{!field}</td>
   </aura:iteration>
  </tr>
</aura:iteration>
```

Or, even better, just use lightning:datatable; it is well-suited to displaying dynamic columns and rows with minimal fuss, and you won't need to redraw the entire table every time a row or cell changes. It also has standard menu- and button-driven actions you can use to provide a consistent user interface.

Comment: I tried using the Lightning:datatable instead of building a html table but I have issue with showing the fields from Sub Query https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/339632/lightning-component-datatable-to-show-fields-from-sub-query can you please help me what I am missing