# Lightning Component Datatable to show fields from Sub Query

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-datatable

I am trying set up a lightning component on the Account that will show the contact and what is the most recent activity associated with it. I tried using the Data table and now I am bale to get the contact records in the lightning component.But I am not sure how to include the subject and OwnerId from the Activities histories in to the Datatable column. Below is the Component and Aura enabled apex class

```
<aura:component controller = "accountSummaryLightningComponent" implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
    <aura:attribute name="ContactList" type="Contact[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="columns" type="List"/>
        
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.myAction}" />
    <lightning:card iconName="standard:work_capacity_usage" title="Key Contacts">
        <aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.ContactList))}">
            <lightning:datatable data="{!v.ContactList }" 
                         columns="{!v.columns }" 
                         keyField="Id"
                         hideCheckboxColumn="true"/>           
            <aura:set attribute="else">
                <div Style="text-align : center"> " There are no key contacts " </div>
            </aura:set>
        </aura:if>
    </lightning:card>
</aura:component>
```

JS Controller

```
({
    myAction : function(component, event, helper) 
    { 
        component.set('v.columns', [
            {label: 'Contact Name', fieldName: 'linkName', type: 'url',
             typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'Contact_Salutation_First_and_Last_Name__c' }, target: '_blank'}}
        ]);
        
        var ConList = component.get("c.getRelatedList");
        ConList.setParams
        ({
            recordId: component.get("v.recordId")
        });
        
        ConList.setCallback(this, function(data) 
        {          
            var state = data.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                var records =data.getReturnValue();
                records.forEach(function(record){
                    record.linkName = '/'+record.Id;
                });
                 component.set("v.ContactList", data.getReturnValue());            
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(ConList);
    }
})
```

Apex Class

```
public with sharing class accountSummaryLightningComponent {
    
    @AuraEnabled
public static list<Contact> getRelatedList(Id recordId)
{
        
List<Contact> Conlist = [Select id,firstname,lastname,Contact_Salutation_First_and_Last_Name__c,(SELECT Id,Subject FROM ActivityHistories ORDER BY ActivityDate DESC LIMIT 1) from Contact where AccountId =: recordId and Key_contact__c = true];
return Conlist;
}
}
```

Can anyone please help how to include the Subject and Owner of the Activity in the datatable

** EDIT**

I updated the controller as suggested below

```
({
    myAction : function(component, event, helper) 
    { 
        component.set('v.columns', [
            {label: 'Contact Name', fieldName: 'linkName', type: 'url',
             typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'Contact_Salutation_First_and_Last_Name__c' }, target: '_blank'}},
             {label: 'Activity Subject', fieldName: 'ActivitySubject', type: 'text'}
        ]);
        
        var ConList = component.get("c.getRelatedList");
        ConList.setParams
        ({
            recordId: component.get("v.recordId")
        });
        
        ConList.setCallback(this, function(data) 
        {          
            var state = data.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                var records = data 
                .getReturnValue()
                .map((row) => ({
                    linkName: '/'+row.Id,
                    ActivitySubject: row && row.ActivityHistories && row.ActivityHistories.length ? row.ActivityHistories[0].Subject : '',
                               }));
                component.set('v.ContactList', records);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(ConList);
    }})
```

The issue is now I see the record ID as hyperlink instead of the `Contact_Salutation_First_and_Last_Name__c`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As David said, you need to "flatten" the data. Also, you should not modify the results from getReturnValue directly, as this can cause problems. Always copy the object first. Here's what you'd want to do:

```
var records = data
    .getReturnValue()
    .map((row) => ({
        ...row,
        linkName: `/${row.Id}`,
        ActivitySubject:
            row && row.ActivityHistories && row.ActivityHistories.length ? row.ActivityHistories[0].Subject : '',
    }));
component.set('v.ContactList', records);
```

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox the issue is now the hyperlink is acting little weird.. I updated the question above, can you please help me if I am missing any thing

Comment: @user81642 Make sure the field name is specified correctly. JavaScript is case-sensitive, so it might be a typo.

Comment: I missed to add the field in the row mapping.. Thank you

Comment: After making this change when I long in another profile user The table looks empty even though the uses has access to Contact and activity history records. Do you think anything else I am missing? I gave the Profiles access to these Aura enabled apex class still no change

Comment: @user81642 "looks empty"? As in, no rows, or rows are there but the fields are blank?

Comment: No rows ... It shows `" There are no key contacts " ` as I given in the component but when as a System administrator I can see the rows for the same record. I double checked logging as the user they have access to the records that are in the table but till it shows in the lightning component `" There are no key contacts " `

Comment: @user81642 What about field level access for the fields? And do they have access to Contacts at all (object level access)? Is this a Guest User Profile, by chance? They'd be limited if that were so. You'll need to look at at a few different settings.

Comment: ActivityHistories is the issue, as the SysAdmin Profile I can view the data. But I am not sure how to check access permission for other profile users on ActivityHistories. But in the UI as the other profile users I can see the past activities

Comment: I changed ActivityHistories  to Tasks and it works now.. Thanks a lot again

Answer (score 1):

You can't use field paths or expressions in the definition of a Lightning data table like this:

```
fieldName: 'ActivityHistories[0].Subject'
```

As you're doing right now with the `linkName` field, you'd need to access those data elements and populate them into synthetic fields on the records. You can then access those fields by name.